# Where are the Glassfish access logs

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

Where are the glassfish access logs located? 
I would expect them to be in domains/domainX/logs.
Is there a setting I need to change to activate access logging?

Thanks

Comment: You must enable http logging first in the administration console before the files show up under domain1/logs/access

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the path seems correct, have a look at this link http://blog.igorminar.com/2009/12/configuring-common-access-log-format-in.html
It shows where you enable access logging in glassfish

---

In case of dead link...

In your GlassFish console you can change the access log format to `common` or `combined`

[image: glassfish console]

You can also use asadmin to make this config change:

```
asadmin set server.http-service.access-log.format="combined"
```

After a restart the log now uses the requested format:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [21/Dec/2009:07:42:45 -0800] "GET /s/1722/3/_/images/icons/star_grey.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [21/Dec/2009:07:42:45 -0800] "GET /images/icons/add_space_32.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [21/Dec/2009:07:42:45 -0800] "GET /images/icons/feed_wizard.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [21/Dec/2009:07:42:45 -0800] "GET /images/icons/people_directory_32.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Comment: It would be helpful for future searchers to include the instructions here in case that blog entry goes away.

Answer (score 6):

Here are details. In Glassfish administration console, open your server configuration "HTTP Service" page and check enabled "Access Logging".
The "Format" field supports `common` or `combined` as shortcut values.

Available variables for format may be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131214215147/https://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/access_log_patterns_and_nicknames), but it is partial too, as the recent `time-taken` is lacking.

Another option is to edit `domain.xml` to set these parameters:

```
<config name="server-config">
  <http-service access-logging-enabled="true">
    <access-log format="common"></access-log>
    <virtual-server id="server" network-listeners="http-listener-1,http-listener-2">
      <http-access-log iponly="true"/>
    </virtual-server>
```

Domain configuration values for `access-log` are listed at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4507/abhaz/index.html

The `http-access-log` node in `virtual-server` allows to set the target directory thanks to the `log-directory` attribute: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4507/abhcm/index.html

Comment: The "available variables" link isn't working - but found the code which gives these. See "Supported access log entry tokens" within http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.web/web-glue/3.0.1/com/sun/enterprise/web/accesslog/DefaultAccessLogFormatterImpl.java

Comment: Thanks. Oracle have probably done some cleanup in its blogs

Comment: @Dazed The alternate link you provided is also dead, any chance of a new link?

Comment: Try https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/master/appserver/web/web-glue/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/web/accesslog/DefaultAccessLogFormatterImpl.java same "Supported access log entry tokens" comment

Comment: @PC - forgot your tag in the above - adding this so you get a prompt - can't edit above